# R/exams Moodle: Cloze with numeric and a string item

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I am trying to use exams package to create my Moodle exams. I want to create a cloze question whit 3 numeric and one string sub-types but I am having problems with the exams2moodle().
Here is a simplification of my code:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
## DATA GENERATION
options(scipen = 999)
#here in my version, I generated the data and solutions, but I simplified the code for a better understanding

cambio_delta <- 20.1
r2 <- 0.97
y0_1 <- 19.56
sol_str<- "Not possible"

```

Question
========

Here goes the question speech

Answerlist
----------
* Question 1 (this is numeric)
* Question 2 (this is numeric)
* Question 3 (this is numeric)
* Question 4 (this is STRING, the answer suppose to be "Not possible")


Meta-information
================
extype: cloze
exclozetype: num|num|num|string
exsolution: `r 100*r2`|`r cambio_delta`|`r y0_1`|`r sol_str`
extol: 0.05|0.05|0.05
exname: regresion
````

When I knit this in the Rmarkdown, it works well, but not with exams2moodle():

```
exams2moodle("regresion.Rmd", n = 8, name = "Exam reg")
```

I get the warning message:

```
Error in split.default(solutionlist, gr) : 
  first argument must be a vector
```

I will appreciate any suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site and to the `r-exams` tag! Thanks for providing a detailed description of your problem. However, I couldn't replicate your problem. I ran your code with both `exams` 2.3-6 (the current CRAN release version) and 2.4-0 (the current R-Forge devel version) and it ran fine without error. Also the import in Moodle worked without problem. Maybe you used an old version of the package? Or possibly `regresion.Rmd` is a different file from the one you posted here?

Comment: Hi @AchimZeileis thank you very much for your reply. You are right, I had al older version of R and "something" wasn`t working well. Now it works well! Thank you

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick feedback. I have turned my comment into an answer so that you can accept that. You can do so by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer (below the vote count). Then your question is flagged officially as "resolved" by StackOverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the R/Markdown exercise into a file `regresion.Rmd` and then ran your code with both `exams` 2.3-6 (the current CRAN release version at the time of writing) and 2.4-0 (the current R-Forge devel version). Everything worked fine without error and the exercises worked as intended after import into Moodle.

I suggest that you update your version of the `exams` package and if necessary of R itself. Then you should be fine.